# Suspicious indexing of non-existent pages

Tags: malware, wordpress, websites

Just recently, the Google search engine started indexing my site with a crazy number of requests. When I logged into the console, 600,000 pages were indexed, and 919,000 more were not indexed. For some reason, non-existent pages like `https://example.art/v17628962.htm` are indexed, only the numbers after the slash change. A closer look reveals that this non-existent page contains some Japanese goods with the appropriate names. I should add that I use Cloudflare. Could it be a malicious script on the site's side?

[image: Screen from google search]

Comment: What do you mean with non-existent page?  Not intended to exists or actually does not exist? Your server might be compromised to serve pages you have not intended.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
In this case, Google indexes pages like /v17628962.htm, and when you click on them, my blog will show that this page does not exist. It shouldn't exist, but Google indexes it anyway (driving some traffic to Japanese products? ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [several similar reports online](https://www.google.com/search?q=site+compromised+SEO+optimization+non+existent+pages). The cause of these problems is usually that the site was compromised and used for malicious SEO.

An excellent summary what has happend and the technical details behind such an attack can be found at [I just dealt with a site hack so elegantly devious that I had to share how it worked](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/i-just-dealt-site-hack-so-elegantly-devious-had-share-jim-whittle/).
In short: attacker compromised the site, changed the sitemap to contain many non-existing links and used htaccess to make sure that instead of the 404 it will serve actual content for these links - but only to the Google bot. Because of the latter you will still see the normal 404, but Google will index the SEO content.

The article is from 2015 so it is likely that the details for your specific compromise vary from the ones in the article. But the basic idea is likely the same.

Comment: Thank you! Now the only problem is to delete all indexed pages and clean up the WordPress